# Ordinary least squares does not optimize error

Tags: regression, least-squares

I'm trying to use polynomial regression to fit the curve

$$X = [0, 1]$$
$$Y = \sin(2 \pi X) + \epsilon$$

where $\epsilon$ is normally distributed with the same $\sigma$ for all $X$

For every value of $x$ I'm creating the vector $[x^0, x^1, \ldots x^n]$ (that is, consisting of the value $x$ raised to the powers $[0, n]$) and trying to fit it using linear regression with ordinary least squares. However, as the size of $n$ increases (empirically, beyond $10$), the *MSE* gets significantly worse (the result of also obvious when plotting)

How does that happen? Isn't ordinary least squares *guaranteed* to find the optimal solution? Since for $n=2$ the solution is much better *MSE* than for $n=10$, the estimator $[b_0, b_1, b_2, 0, 0, 0, \ldots]$ would produce better *MSE* with $n=10$ than the one that ordinary least squares finds. What I'm I misunderstanding?

Below is sample python code (if anyone is interested in running it)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def inputs(X, n):
    return np.column_stack([X**i for i in range(n+1)])


def targets(X):
    T0 = np.sin(2* np.pi * X) + 5
    T = T0 + 0.1 * np.random.randn(*X.shape)
    return T, T0

class Regressor:
    def fit(self, X, T):
        T = T.reshape(-1, 1)
        self.B = np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ T

    def predict(self, X):
        Y = X @ self.B
        return Y.ravel()


num_samples = 100
num_dimensions = 20

regressor = Regressor()
X = np.linspace(0, 1, num_samples)
T, T0 = targets(X)

X_ = inputs(X, num_dimensions)

regressor.fit(X_, T)
Y = regressor.predict(X_)
MSE = ((Y - T)**2).sum()

plt.plot(X, T0, 'C0')
plt.plot(X, T, 'oC0')
plt.plot(X, Y, 'C1')
plt.show()
```

Comment: There are many, many things that can go wrong, which is why you really need to display your results after reducing your problem to a minimal reproducible example.  I suspect (without any proof yet) that you are running into floating point problems due to the severe near-collinearity of all those powers of `x`.  If that's the case, the solution is to use an orthogonal polynomial basis.  (A far better solution is never to do polynomial regression, but presumably this is not intended as a practical example.)

Comment: @whuber: this code *is* a minimai reproducible example. It's hard to list the results in any other form. Theoretically though, do I correctly understand that increasing variables should produce at least equally small MSE on the training set, by definition?

Comment: You haven't given us an example yet: in addition to the code, *exactly what does it output?*